# One of my app DLLs is being treated like an assembly in my InstallShield MSI installer

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-installer, .net-5, installshield

I'm creating a new installer using ***InstallShield 2020 R3*** for the new ***WPF .NET 5.0*** version of one of our software products. It works except for one issue. I have searched the ***Revenera*** community site and the Internet for answers, but find none. This project is on a deadline, so I would like to find an answer as quickly as possible. I have submitted a ticket to ***Revenera***, but hope that, maybe, someone else has a simple answer for me.

**The Issue:**
A single product DLL that is not a third-party assembly, but one of the class libraries build with the product, is not being copied to the destination folder during install. The install log shows that the operation that the installer is using to copy the DLL is ***AssemblyCopy*** rather than the operation, ***FileCopy*** that is used for all other components in the application.

I've checked, double-checked, triple-checked... on and on the component properties and see that the properties are identical to all of the other DLL components in the InstallShield project.

Any clues will be much appreciated. I don't see a way to attach the install.log and the InstallShield project file, otherwise I would.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I made one more attempt to find answers by searching for Assemblies in ***InstallShield*** help. I decided to post the answer so that somebody else searching in this forum could find a resolution to the issue.

I found that assembly components for an MSI installer end up in the ***MsiAssembly*** table, which is accessed via the ***Direct Editor*** in *InstallShield*. The image below shows how to get to the table and shows that the table is empty now, but initially had my problem DLL in it. After I cleared the table, the DLL is copied to the installation folder as intended.

[image]